# Probability of the median of three independent outcomes

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, median

I have come across a statistics problem that I want to solve but I don't know where to begin. The problem is the following

- What is the probability that the median of three random numbers between 60 and 100 is greater than or equal to 75?

Analytically I was able to use R to calculate that the probability is `0.695884...`, however I don't know how mathematically to solve this. Can someone show me how to derive the solution so I can follow the steps and thought-process?

Comment: Hint: the median is defined to be a number $m$ such that $P(X\leq m) \ge \frac{1}{2} $ and $P(X \ge m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Is X any random value between 60-100? If so I don't see how this can be true. If the median value of three random values is say m = 65, there isn't a 50% chance or higher that another random value X would be below that.

Comment: It is asking the probability of the median $m \ge 75$. Why choose $m=65$ in your question? You need to assume you have $X,Y,Z$ that are randomly chosen numbers from $60$ to $100$ and then calculate the probability that median $m \ge 75$.

Comment: This doesn't help me still and I don't see how your initial comment is true. If you draw three random values, $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, one of those three values would be the median value. Lets say $X = 62$, $Y = 73$, and $Z = 84$. Then $m = Y = 73$. How is it true then that $P(X \le m) \ge \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Well if I have the numbers $62,73$ and $84$ and $X$ is the random variable that represents the number I choose randomly from the set $\{62,73,84\}$ then $P(X \le 73) = \frac{2}{3} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X \ge 73) = \frac{2}{3} \ge \frac{1}{2}$. In your problem though $X,Y,Z$ are random and so $m$ becomes a random variable dependent upon $X,Y,Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the probability of four cases:

1. $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all at least $75$;
2. $X < 75$, but $Y \ge 75$ and $Z \ge 75$;
3. $Y < 75$, but $X \ge 75$ and $Z \ge 75$;
4. $Z < 75$, but $X \ge 75$ and $Z \ge 75$.

These cases are disjoint, and in each of them, the median of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ is also at least $75$. On the other hand, if none of these cases apply, then at least two of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are less than $75$ - making the median less than $75$ as well.

(Also, there is a slight difference in probability here depending on whether we choose $X,Y,Z$ to be random real numbers in the range $[60,100]$, or random integers from the set $\{60,61,\dots,100\}$. Be sure which of these you want!)